# How do I check that a method is queued for execution in Java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have a class with method sampleMethod. How do I check if the Object of a class has sampleMethod() and that sampleMethod() was called and  also cancel it's execution?

```
public class MyClass {

    public checkMethodIsQueuedForExecution() {
        Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("sampleMethod");

        // Check if previously called, and stop it.

        if (m != null) {
            m.invoke(this, null); // calls sampleMethod()
        }
    }

    public void sampleMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I have figured out that I can check the object of class has method using reflect but how do to check if this method is queued for execution? if yes then cancel it's execution.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is similar to what objective-C has cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget, performSelector. I am trying to find same mechanism for Java for Android app.

Comment: I have no experience with objective-C, but looking at the documentation of those methods indicates that you're going about this the wrong way. Invoking a method is immediate. Reflection won't help you here. Whatever API you're using should offer a way to cancel an asynchronous request. Perhaps if you provided a [mre] demonstrating what you're after and the problem you're having someone could be of more help.

Comment: Re, "//Check if previously called, and stop it." Why not simply write `sampleMethod()` so that it only works one time?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an example like this;

```
    // instance variable will control only if this instance's method 
    // was executed or not
    private volatile boolean isQueued = false;

    public void checkMethodIsQueuedForExecution() 
                throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
                       IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
                       InvocationTargetException {

        Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("sampleMethod");
        if (null == m) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if this instance's method previously called, and stop it.
        synchronized(this) { 
            if (isQueued) {
                return;
            }
            isQueued = true;

            m.invoke(this, null); // calls sampleMethod()

        }

    }
```